# running tests on xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 4.3 and i'm not getting how to run the tests, or at least, how the see the test results, failed or passed.

I've a project with two targets, `foo` and `fooTests`. The tests are the default implementation; a simple tearDown and setup function and a testExample method with a `STFail(@"not implemented")`

where i'm supposed to see this message? on the scheme dropdown, there seems to be only `foo`. What i need to do to run the fooTests target and see output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this by clicking on the "Run" checkbox in the Edit Scheme dialog. On the left there's a list of tabs. Choose "Build". Then there's a list of actions ("Analyze", "Test", "Run", "Profile", etc) on the right-hand side. Make sure "Run" is checked.

Then press "OK" and then Clean and Build your project.

Answer (score 5):

From the menu `Product`->`Test` or the Cmd+U (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) keyboard shortcut will run the test for `foo` target.

Comment: Various things can be missing/wrong in the Xcode configuration that prevent test to work as they should.

Comment: What can go wrong in OP's situation where he has default project with default targets configured for testing?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new scheme to run a different target.  Click the left portion of your Schemes bar (top left hand corner) and you should get a drop-down menu where "New Scheme" is an option--create a new scheme and choose fooTests as the Target.

Comment: i get 'the scheme fooTests is not configured for running: has nothing configured for running and has no executable configured to run. edit to configure the run action'

Comment: Huh. In that case I'm not sure, I've never seen an error like that.  Hopefully someone else will come along who knows how to fix it.  Sorry!

Comment: I absolutely get this error mentioned in the comment above: 'the scheme fooTests is not configured for running: has nothing configured for running and has no executable configured to run. edit to configure the run action' ... this error is driving me crazy. I can't get the tests to run anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Eimantas' answer covers running the tests. Open the log navigator to see the results. More detailed information is available in the following article:

[Setting Up OCUnit Unit Testing in Xcode 4](http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/05/setting-up-ocunit-unit-testing-in-xcode-4/)